# How do you window.onload Javascript classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onload

I'm trying to dynamically change my html by calling my Javascript class in jQuery.  I keep getting an Uncaught Reference error.  I know I have to window.onload my class somewhere.  I've tried to load it before and after the class, before and after my jquery, right before the end of my HTML body, but I keep getting Uncaught Reference errors for the class I'm calling and the prototype (randomCard()) that I use in my jQuery.

I've also tried switching the order of script files at the end of my HTML body.  I'm new to Javascript.

### game.js

```
function CardsAgainstHumanity () {
    this.blackCards = [
      "How did I lose my virginity?",
      "Why can't I sleep at night?",
      "What's that smell?",
      "I got 99 problems but ______________ ain't one.",
      "Maybe she's born with it.  Maybe it's ______________.",
      "What's the next Happy Meal toy?",
      "Here is the church. </br> Here is the steeple. </br> Open the doors </br> And there is ________________.",
      "It's a pity that kids these days are all getting involved with _______________."

      ];

    this.whiteCards = [];

    this.score = 0;

    randomCard();
}




CardsAgainstHumanity.prototype.randomCard = function () {
  var random = this.blackCards[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.blackCards.length)];
  return random;

};
```

### index.js

```
$(document).ready (function() {

      $(".black-cards").on("click", function () {
      $(this).text(randomCard());

    });

});
```

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <title>Cards Against Humanity</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
       integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
       <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen">
    </head>


  <body>


    <div class="container">

        <div class="black-cards"> </div>    <!-- Black Cards -->


    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/game.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>


  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have to call the `randomCard()` reference from a reference to an object instance, including from within the constructor function (like `this.randomCard()`).

Comment: Worked!  Thank you...